# iOS get callback when app opens with URL from object other than the app delegate

Tags: ios, facebook, nsnotifications

I'm building an `iOS framework` with includes some `Facebook` functionality. When a user log's into Facebook the user is taken to the `Facebook app`, and then Facebook reopens the original app using a URL including a session token.

As this is a framework I can't use

```
application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:.
```

Is there a `NSNotificationCenter` key I can use or something similar to get a callback when the app reopens from `Facebook`?

Comment: You can require projects including your framework to forward the data to you (which could be via a custom notification).

Comment: The best will be to prepare a method that will be called by the app that will integrate your framework. Quite common solution, smth like: + (BOOL)handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
    sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication;